# NameError: global name 'client' is not defined

Tags: python

Here i did the python class for connecting mongo and get the data  from mongo database and process it i did the unit test cases for this i got following error

NameError: global name 'client' is not defined

python class  :

```
 from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure, AutoReconnect
 import pymongo
 from pymongo import MongoClient

 class ConnectionError(Exception):
   pass



class ChkMongo:

item_list=[]
dict1={}

def makeMongocon(self):

    global client
    try :
        client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)

    except AutoReconnect, e:
        raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))

def findRecords(self):
    self.db = client.serv
    for item in self.db.serv.find():
        self.item_list.insert(0,item)
    return self.item_list





if __name__ == '__main__':
  c=ChkMongo()
  c.makeMongocon()
  print(c.findRecords())
```

my unit test case

```
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
 import unittest;
 from app.ChkMongo import *  

class TestChkMongo(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.c=ChkMongo()

def test_makeMongocon(self):
    self.assertRaises(ConnectionFailure,self.c.makeMongocon)
def test_findRecords(self):
    print(self.c.findRecords())
    self.assertDictContainsSubset({'name':'matthew'},self.c.findRecords())
def test_calculate_charge_with_tax(self):
    self.assertAlmostEqual(290,self.c.calculate_charge_with_tax('matthew'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

i got following error when run the test cases but run the python script that will work fine

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/test_chkMongo.py", line 16, in test_findRecords
    print(self.c.findRecords())
  File "n/app/ChkMongo.py", line 29, in findRecords
    self.db = client.serventer code here
NameError: global name 'client' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you are using a global variable here for `client`. That should be an instance variable of the `ChkMongo` class.

```
class ChkMongo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.item_list = []
    self.dict1 = {}

  def makeMongocon(self):
    try:
        self.client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    except AutoReconnect, e:
        raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))

  def findRecords(self):
    self.db = self.client.serv
    for item in self.db.serv.find():
        self.item_list.insert(0,item)
    return self.item_list
```

Note that `item_list` and `dict1` also need to be instance properties, not class ones.

Comment: when i change as instance variable i got following error when i run the unit test

i got following error :
  self.db = self.client.serv
AttributeError: ChkMongo instance has no attribute 'client'

Comment: Well, your `test_findRecords` method is not calling the `makeMongocon` method to set up the connection. How are you expecting that to work?

Answer (score 1):

For me it happens when running my test with Python **3.6.x** and Python **2.x**.
Some exception names are not available in Python **2.x**.

For example with `ConnectionError`:

in Python **2.x**, using `python` interpreter, I get a `NameError` because it does not recognize it.

```
>>> raise ConnectionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ConnectionError' is not defined
```

in Python **3.6.x**, using `python3` interpreter, I get the right `ConnectionError`

```
>>> raise ConnectionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ConnectionError
```

It can be tricky when working with multiple versions of Python or different venv. Hope it helps with the debugging.